# Unity 5 Vertical movement with rigid body and velocity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was watching this developer writing a piece of code where all you have to do is move up and down. I tried his code segment but the `.velocity` doesn't work in unity 5.01 because he was working 4.3. I need some help making a smooth way to move up and down without using translate because that is very choppy.

```
public float maxSpeed = 10f;
void FixedUpdate () {
    float move = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical");
    rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2(move * maxSpeed, rigidbody2D.velocity.x);
}
```

Comment: Code snippet is for HTML / CSS and JS. It can't be use with C#. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Comment: _[The velocity is specified as a vector with components in the X and Y directions (there is no Z direction in 2D physics). The value is **not usually set directly but rather by using forces**.](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D-velocity.html)_ ; some more details: _[In most cases **you should not modify the velocity** directly, as this can result in **unrealistic behaviour**. Don't set the velocity of an object every physics step, this will lead to unrealistic physics simulation.](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-velocity.html)_ - that explains the choppiness

Comment: Check out http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/RigidbodiesOverview.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you just mixed up parameters inside the Vector2 constructor. Try

```
rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2(rigidbody2D.velocity.x, move * maxSpeed);
```